# Is the Frattini subgroup of the Schur cover of a finite simple group equal to the center?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a nonabelian finite simple group, and $\tilde{G}\rightarrow G$ its Schur cover. This is the unique perfect central extension of maximum order, and its kernel is the Schur multiplier $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})$.

Is the Frattini subgroup of $\tilde{G}$ equal to its center? In other words, is any subgroup of $\tilde{G}$ which surjects onto $G$ equal to $\tilde{G}$?

The Schur cover of a perfect group as a universal central extension, but I'm not aware of any universal properties, which makes understanding it difficult.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun Added some more details!

Comment: That's better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the Schur cover of a non-abelian simple group and let $Z:=Z(G)$. Suppose that $G$ has a maximal subgroup $M$, which does not contain $Z$. Then $ZM=G$ and we get the contradiction $G'=M'<G$.

Comment: I guess you want $M$ to be maximal normal?

Comment: Any thoughts if the answer remains positive if we replace nonabelian finite simple with perfect? In this case one should ask if the Frattini subgroup is equal to the kernel of the Schur cover

Comment: No, I don't want M to be normal (the Frattini subgroup is the intersection of all maximal subgroups). To your second question: Yes, the same argument works for perfect groups, since Schur covers of perfect groups are perfect.

Comment: If $M$ is not normal, why must $ZM = G$?

Comment: $ZM$ is a subgroup, but it's larger than $M$.